# Backdrop-filter doesn't work on multiple layer elements

Tags: html, css

Backdrop-filter doesn't seem to work on child if the parent already have backdrop-filter

Check this example:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 24px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  /* transparency to see the blur effect */
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  /* blur effect */
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #FFF;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  /* transparency to see the blur effect */
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  /* blur effect */
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem facere accusantium ullam omnis culpa. Blanditiis, placeat ab incidunt doloremque voluptate, natus deserunt, animi culpa deleniti illum voluptas a accusamus amet.
</div>
```

As for the output, it does seems to apply the blur effect but not what intended should be. It's like using opacity and backdrop-filter together that's why it shows a glowing text background. Is there a workaround to this or is it just not allowed to put multiple layers of backdrop-filter?

Comment: Don't *just* use transform `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` where transform is not he right tool (I know it's suggested far too many times - it's not your fault). A flexbox with centered content might be better in terms of responsiveness and not losing any content above the fold.

Comment: Thank you @disinfor, that seems to be the same problem.

Comment: Thank you @RokoC.Buljan for the suggestion, I updated the post accordingly.